# show gridview based on roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I just want to display gridview where the roles are Admin and Teacher except student.

```
   SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE [Role]=@Role" 
  <SelectParameters>
  <asp:SessionParameter Name="Role" DefaultValue="Admin" DefaultValue="Teacher" SessionField="Role" Type="String" />
 </SelectParameters>
```

I tried to set Admin and Teacher both as defaultValue but it cant work.

Comment: Are you trying it with both default values at the same time as per your code sample? If so, remove one and see if that works. Alternatively couldn't you just have your query set up something like: SElect * from users where role <> 'student'

Comment: i only want every type of roles to appear in gridview except for student.. means i have a few roles like admin ,teacher..

Comment: In that case my suggested SQL will work as it'll populate the gridview with all users except those that are assigned role 'student'.

Comment: No problem can you mark my answer (below) as the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Never ever `SELECT *...`

Comment: It's not the worst thing you could do but yes you should specify the fields, I put * as I didn't know what fields the user had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:  you just have your query set up something like:

```
Select * from users where role <> 'student'
```